# Why does QPrintDialog not bring up the native print dialog on Cinnamon desktop

Tags: c++, qt

I am using qt 5.6 on Linux mint; the print dialog that comes up is not the one that all the other applications bring up, so I guess it is the qt dialog and not the native one. I need some of the settings on the native dialog. Can I change this behaviour some how?

Answer (score 0):

No. Cinnamon uses GTK, which is a different library. You may try to make Qt look a lot like native Cinnamon apps, but under the hood it uses it's own widgets and if they don't provide certain functionality, you have to write your own class inheriting QPrintDialog to get the behaviour you want.

Actually, the Qt team is struggling to make Qt wrap and use some of the actual native elements to unify the experience among applications on a given OS, but they are still experimenting as this is quite complicated. See [this post on their blog](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/02/06/native-look-feel/).

Comment: And yet for QFileDialog there is an option QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog for which the docs say it means "Don't use the native file dialog. By default, the native file dialog is used unless you use a subclass of QFileDialog that contains the Q_OBJECT macro, or the platform does not have a native dialog of the type that you require." So I was hoping something similar might be available for the print dialog. I too get the impression it is a work in progress.